# Display a column of data using a temp table

Tags: sql

I am having trouble displaying a column using a temp table.
I would like the data displayed in order shown below. I needed to use the
temp table as the same formulas used for calculating other columns were inaccurate.
Please use 3rd line of coded from the bottom of sample and slot in correct position. Thanks
Bet - Collect - Profit - Roi

```
SELECT Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (), Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER (), Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER (), df.RaceDateTime
FROM  dbo.RaceJunction AS rj 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UKHRace AS uk ON rj.UKHRaceId = uk.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DataForm AS df ON rj.DataFormId = df.Id


SELECT Roi = Profit / Bet
FROM  temp_table
WHERE (1 = 1)
```

Comment: That's not a good reason to use a temp table

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a temp tale: nest the query  or use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
SELECT *, Profit/Bet As ROI
FROM (
    SELECT Bet = COUNT(*) OVER (), Collect = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER (), Profit = SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN (([BetfairWinSP] - 1) * .95 + 1) END) OVER () - COUNT(*) OVER (), df.RaceDateTime
    FROM  dbo.RaceJunction AS rj 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UKHRace AS uk ON rj.UKHRaceId = uk.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DataForm AS df ON rj.DataFormId = df.Id
) t
```

Comment: I received this message    Multi part identifier "df.RaceDateTime"could not be bound

Comment: Is that actually a column in the DataForm table? Also, those `OVER ()` are a code smell. You probably want a `PARTITION BY` in there.

Comment: Yes it is a column in the Dataform table. How can I include PARTITION BY ? I am a complete novice at this. Thanks